# Добавление поля в плагин WordPress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, плагин

Здравствуйте!

Как можно добавить поле в уже имеющийся плагин(evont, но думаю не так важно)? Сейчас есть поля: имя, описание, ссылка. Все это преобразуется в отзыв на сайте. Нужно добавить возможность устанавливать изображение(человека оставившего отзыв) через админ панель,а именно этот плагин. Где все это собирается файл нашел, но там ничего не вызывается из БД, все через хуки(вроде так). Файл для админки этого плагина не могу найти, более того, ни один не могу найти.

Где лежат файлы плагинов, которые выводятся в админ панели(поля ввода и тд)? Как правильнее составить запрос для такой ситуации(добавление фото)?

Спасибо.

```html
<?php 
 /* Testimonials  ---------------------------------------------*/
 
 add_shortcode('testimonials', 'evont_testimonials');
 
 function evont_testimonials($atts, $content = null) { 
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'post_count' => '',
    'style' => '',
    ), $atts)); 
   
  
  //initial variables
  $out=''; 
  $border='';
  

  if ($style=='light'):
  $text_style='jx-light';
  elseif($style=='dark'):
  $text_style='jx-dark';
  endif;
  
  if ($border=='yes'):
  $border='border';
  else:
  $border='';
  endif;
  
  //initial variables
  $out=''; 
  
  $out ='<div class="jx-evont-testimonials-1">';
  
  $args = array('post_type' => 'testimonials','orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC','showposts' => $post_count ); 
 
 
   $loop = new WP_Query( $args );   
   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  
   
   //function code
    
    $testimonial_jobposition = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'jx_evont_testimonial_business_name', true );  
    
    
    
    $out .='
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="item">
      <div class="jx-evont-testimonial-details '.$border.'">
       <div class="icon"><img src="http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/qute.png" alt=""></div>
       <div class="description">'.get_the_content().'</div>
       <div class="user_img"></div>
       <div class="name">'. get_the_title() .'</div>
       <div class="position">'.$testimonial_jobposition.'</div>
      </div> 
     </div>
    </div>
    ';
    
    
       
    endwhile;
    
    
    $out .='</div>';
   
   
   
   wp_reset_query(); 
  
  //return output
  return $out;
 }
```

Comment: вы добавили форму вывода
`$args = array('post_type' => 'testimonials','orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC','showposts' => $post_count ); `
выбрать все посты из пост тайпа testimonials, сортировка по дате по-возрастанию

Comment: http://support.janxcode.com/evont-docs/testimonials/
вот на сайте есть пример, как работает ваш `evont_testimonials` он берет миниатюру поста и выводит как изображение пользователя, который оставил комментарий. Зачем придумывать велосипед?

Comment: @eugene_v дело в том, что вы возможно не дочитали до конца этот пост. У меня выводит отзывы, как в конце поста(на следующей странице), почему у автора видео отзывы в таком виде это не ясно,так как и возможности слайдера из коробки нет.

Comment: Вы тему покупали, у вас есть Visual Composser? Какую тему вы используете, откуда у вас этот плагин, он с темой приобретался?

Comment: @eugene_v вы клоните в сторону саппорта, то не вариант. Тема не куплена, но работает. VC есть.Тема Evont Version: 1.0

Comment: я не клоню в сторону саппорта, я пытаюсь узнать то, что вы должны были описать в теле сообщения. Вам нужна помощь, но мы не телепаты, прежде чем помочь, нужно понять с чем имеешь дело

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась добавлением функции `get_the_post_thumbnail()` в нужное место переменной `$out`